# How to save the result of tweepy filter into a json file?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm setting a streaming listener, and then filter the tweets by a specific keyword and the location bounding box, and I want to save the filtering result into a json file.
But I found that all the result from streaming listener is in the json file, not just the filtered results.
I think it probably because the 'save json file' code is in the class Mystreamlistener, and the filtering code is behind it. 
But I don't know how to revise my code. Here is my code:

This is my first code:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
import tweepy, sys
from time import sleep
import csv

consumer_key = 'XX'
consumer_secret = 'XX'
access_token = 'XX'
access_token_secret = 'XX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

box = [-178.2,6.6,-49.0,83.3]
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text.encode('utf-8'))
        with open('government.json', 'a') as f:
            tweet=str(status.user)
            nPos=tweet.index("_json=")
            tweet=tweet[nPos+6:]
            ePos=tweet.index("id=")
            tweet=tweet[:ePos-2]
            f.write(tweet+'\n')

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=['trump'], locations=(box))
```

I already tried the answer from Ajeet Khan in question: 
[How to save a tweepy Twitter stream to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130124/how-to-save-a-tweepy-twitter-stream-to-a-file)
But I don't know how to call the class, the second code is what I tried according to Ajeet Khan's answer.

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
import tweepy, sys
from time import sleep
import csv

consumer_key = 'XX'
consumer_secret = 'XX'
access_token = 'XX'
access_token_secret = 'XX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

box = [-178.2,6.6,-49.0,83.3]
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text.encode('utf-8'))
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, status):
        #print data
        with open('fetched_tweets.txt','a') as tf:
            tf.write(status)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=['trump'], locations=(box))
StdOutListener()
```